# Retrieve active incidents for a contact

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I have the id for a contact record but I need to know if there are any active incidents for that contact.

Retrieving a contact I can do with no probs, but I don't know how to retrieve related records.

Does anyone have a code snippet to do this? I think I really just need the line that makes the call!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: need to know what ways have you tried for the same?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I have no idea how to do it. I can retrieve a record if I have the id, but I don't know how to look for related records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already get contact, use the same way to find incidents. Instead of *ContactSet* you will need *IncidentSet*. In filter expression put condition that *CustomerId/Id eq guid'" + yourContactId + "'* and *StateCode eq '0'* (for active cases).

Hope it helps!

PS I suppose that you are using oData, question has **javascript** tag.

Comment: Looks good - but another small problem has shown up. I can't find an ID field on the page. Can I use the Execution Context to get the ID?

Comment: you mean ID of Contact? On which form you want to call this? if it is Contact form than you can use: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()